# Syntax to export 4 MySQL DB tables to XML?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I'm trying to create a PHP file that will export the contents of 4 tables in my MySQL database to an XML file that will be downloaded to the workstation.  The tables are orders, orders_products, orders_products_attributes and orders total.

I am able to do the export to xml via phpmyadmin for these tables, but it doesn't show me the syntax it's using to create it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this a "practical, answerable question"? What help are you asking for exactly?

Comment: I believe so. ;)  Marc B nailed it! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke the following command from a shell_exec() inside PHP. You'd need to add your login details alongside the -p option, of course.

```
mysqldump -p --xml databasename orders orders_products orders_products_attributes orders > dump.xml
```

details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_xml).